# update without select active record yii

Tags: activerecord, yii, criteria

I try update num_of_gifts without select use yii active record and CDbCriteria
this is my code:

```
$attributes = array('num_of_gifts' => 'num_of_gifts'+1);
$condition = 'bla bla';
$params = array(bla bla);
Gifts::model()->updateAll($attributes, $condition, $params);
```

all I get that "1" at the num_of_gifts cell, 
is it possible increase 1 to num_of_gifts? or I need select the amount of num_of_gifts and after it use update?

Comment: Did you really mean to write `'num_of_gifts'+1`? You are adding a string and an integer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just updating counters you could use Yii's [updateCounters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateCounters-detail) method.

Example for updating all:

```
Gifts::model()->updateCounters(array('num_of_gifts'=>1));
```

That method takes a condition to update a specific record, but if you don't include a condition it will update all records.

[edit]

If you want to update selected records based on a condition, the format is this:

```
Gifts::model()->updateCounters(
        array('num_of_gifts'=>1),
        array('condition' => "param = :param"),
        array(':param' => 'paramvalue'),
    );
```

Comment: thanks works well, but you have little mistake the condition is not array.

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right. I copied the format from a wiki page and it was incorrect! That will teach me :) I'm glad you got it figured out though. You can also use saveCounters() on a specific model. That's what I normally do.

Answer (score 0):

Since Yii 1.1.8 there is simplified method for updating counters:

```
Gifts::model()->saveCounters(array('num_of_gifts'=>1));
```

See:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/282/using-counters-with-activerecord/
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#saveCounters-detail